# Access date_subscribed from a many to many field on a for loop template Django

Tags: django, loops, templates, manytomanyfield, m2m

I have these models,

```
class Place(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
   related_name='places', default=1)
   subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(AppUser, through='PlaceSubscriber')
   def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python
       return self.name

class PlaceSubscriber(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_subscribed = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('place', 'user')
```

I want to access the date_subscribed fields on this for loop inside my template

```
{% for o in place.subscribers.all %}
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
    <span class="pull-left">
         {{ forloop.counter }}. &emsp;
    </span>
    <span class="pull-left">
         <strong>{{ o.full_name }}</strong>
         <p>Email: <i>{{ o.email }}</i> | Date Subscribed: <i> {{ 
          o.place__placesubscriber__date_subscribed }} </i> </p>
    </span>
    <span class="pull-right">
    <span class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" 
       onclick="sendPushNotificationToUser('{{ o.ionic_id }}'); return 
       false;">Send Message</span>
    <span class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="deletePlaceUser({{ place.id 
        }}, {{ o.id }}); return false;  ">
      Unsubscribe
   </span>

   </button>
   </span>
   </a>
{% endfor %}
```

I can access the date_subscribed field outside this foorloop like this:

```
{% for each in place.placesubscriber_set.all %}
    {{ each.date_subscribed }}
{% endfor %}
```

But haven´t figure out how to it access inside the other one.

*UPDATE*

This is my view

```
class PlaceDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Place
    template_name = 'place/place_detail.html'
```

And this is the url pattern

```
url(r'^place/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.PlaceDetailView.as_view(), name='detail_place'),
```

Comment: What do you mean by access the data inside the for loop? You can place this for loop inside the other one and voilla! But you probably need to output one specific date_subscribed in each step, right? In that case I would remodel the data passed from your view to put the correspondent data to the step of the loop using lists.

Comment: @Tico Yes I want to display each subscribed date for each subscriber of that specific place, I am creating my view like this `url(r'^place/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.PlaceDetailView.as_view(), name='detail_place')"`, so I'm not sending any data yet, do I have to create the Detail view manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually try to make a good query to deal with simple data structure in my template, avoiding complicated logic.

I would replace the view for a simple one that makes the query that you want (hopefully):

```
def place_detail(request):

    data = PlaceSubscriber.objects.all().values(
        'user__full_name',
        'user__email',
        'place__name',
        'date_subscribed'
    )

    return render(request,'place.html',{'data':data})
```

This generates a list of dictionaries with the query keys. You can display this data now by:

```
{% for el in data %}
    {el.user__full_name}
    {el.date_subscribed}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Well, I'm not sure if is that you want, but you can change the query values to get exactly what you want.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i think in your views.py file you should do this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Place
def placeview(request):
    place = Place()
    return render(request, 'place.html', {'place':place})
```

Answer (score 0):

I Ended up following @Tico approach,I updated my view so it had less logic than before, this was my update:

Updated my urls.py file, stopped using generic Detail view Class

```
url(r'^place/(?P<place_id>\d+)$', views.place_detail, name='detail_place'),
```

Updated the detail view method on views.py file to return the data I need from both models:

```
def place_detail(request, place_id):
    place = get_object_or_404(Place, pk=place_id)
    placeSubscribers = PlaceSubscriber.objects.all().filter(place=place).values(
         'user__full_name',
         'user__email',
         'user__ionic_id',
         'place__name',
         'date_subscribed',
         'pk'
     )
     return render(request, 'place/place_detail.html', {'place': place, 'placeSubscribers': placeSubscribers})
```

Anda Finally updated my template For to pull the data from placeSubscribers, there I can access the date_subscribed field

```
 {% for placeSubscriber in placeSubscribers %}
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
        <span class="pull-left">
          {{ forloop.counter }}. &emsp;
        </span>
        <span class="pull-left">
        <strong>{{ placeSubscriber.user__full_name }}</strong>
         <p>Email: <i>{{ placeSubscriber.user__email }}</i> | Date Subscribed: <i> {{ placeSubscriber.date_subscribed }} </i> </p>
        </span>
        <span class="pull-right">
          <span class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" onclick="sendPushNotificationToUser('{{ placeSubscriber.user__ionic_id }}'); return false;">Send Message</span>
         <span class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="deletePlaceUser({{ place.id }}, {{ placeSubscriber.pk }}); return false;  ">
           Unsubscribe
           </span>
          </button>
         </span>
         </a>
{% endfor %}
```